# WinXP Raid 1 Failure Boot Issue

Tags: windows-xp, boot, raid

Here's my problem. I have a computer that was set up with RAID1, 2 HDDs and had a failure to one from some power surge issues.

If attempting to boot each drive on their own:
- The HDD in Port0 is bad and unable to boot on its own and gets a Windows "Please insert repair disk" error. The BIOS recognizes this as a RAID1 disk in a degraded state.
- THe HDD in Port1 boots up until it gets to login and then does an infinite "Log in" -> "Load Settings" -> "Log Off" loop that I cannot break. This occurs in Safe Mode as well. The BIOS sees this as a Non-RAID disk

If attempting to boot the drives together, the "good" drive as primary boot device things are fine.

I have a backup drive that I want to add to the RAID array alongside the "Good disk" but am unable to do so unless I can get to the Intel RAID utility in Windows (I forget its name).

How can I get this drive to boot without the infinite cycle? CHKDSK /F didn't repair it and attempting to load the Win XP CD gives BSOD regardless of the HDD.

The fact that the disks boot when together if selecting the Port1 as primary boot but not alone baffles me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

Boot up the good disk NOT in RAID mode (change the controller to JBOD, or use a different controller).

Take an image (I like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)) of the working disk and image it to a network drive or other location.

Put TWO (possibly NEW) working disks on to the RAID controller and create a NEW RAID array.

Using the image you took earlier, re-image the new RAID array.

Boot up with the Windows CD and "Repair" the array (this should rebuild the Master Boot Record to look at the new array and allow you to boot it).

Profit.

p.s. I would keep the working disk (and the faulty disk) aside throughout the whole process above in case anything goes wrong.  That way, you have not lost anything and you are no worse off.  You can be free to experiment and play around (learn), and get it working the way you want it to work.

Comment: I was afraid that was what it was coming to. It just boggles my mind that the mirror setup fails to work independently (isn't that the point?)